# jquery dataTable stuck serverside

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am developing a data archiving system which is playing with millions/billions of data. I have already created the customer logbook with php-jquery data table **serverside processing** which is increasing day by day (with more than 10 columns each row). 
currently it has 5 millions of row. now the logbook becomes tremendously slow(almost unusable- ***just show processing*** ....).

**note:** the logbook is created from several tables on the fly

is there any other way to deal with this kind of application ?

**my logbook code is as follows:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bFilter": true,
        "bSearchable": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aoColumnDefs" : [ { 'bSortable' : false, 'aTargets' :  [6,7]} ], // unclickable or unsortable column in the header
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "oTableTools": { 
            "aButtons": [ "copy", "csv", "xls", {
            "sExtends": "pdf",
            "sPdfMessage": "Full Logbook of Customer:  <?php echo "$customerName"; ?>  "
         }],
        //"aButtons": [ "select_all", "select_none" ],
        "sSwfPath": "js/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        },
        "sAjaxSource": "server-processing/logbook.php?customer=<?php echo $customer; ?>",
        "fnServerData": function( sUrl, aoData, fnCallback ){
            $.ajax( {
                "url": sUrl,
                "data": aoData,
                "success": fnCallback,
                "dataType": "json",
                "cache": false
            });
        }   
    });

    oTable.columnFilter({ sPlaceHolder: "head:after",
        aoColumns: [ 
            { type: "text" },
            { type: "text" },
            { type: "text" },
            { type: "text" },
            { type: "text" }
        ]
    });

    var asInitVals = new Array();
    var oTable = $('table.display').dataTable();                    

});
```

Comment: please tell me, you are using pagination, right?! (sorry, i don't know enough datatable plugin)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered to implement pagination on the server side?

Check this link:
http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: ya i think the important part is the server side script, just what OP didn't have posted